# Advice on MongoDB data modelling

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I have a schema written in mongoose, I want suggestions on how to improve this schema to scale.

```
members: [{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    roles: [String],
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        default: [],
    }],
    assignedBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    assignedTime: Date,
}],
roles: [{
    title: String,
    color: String,
    textColor: String,
    roleType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
    },
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        default: [],
    }]
}]
```

The Reason we have both roles and permission in members is because i want user to edit the permissions of individual members even if they are not in the role.

Now my question how does scaling work on this model. lets consider i have million members then the array will have million members data.
My questions are as follows.

- Mongo will reach it's 16MB limit, Will this model work well with sharding?
- What about performance i have to see if the user has permission or not?
- And is there any other way i can improve this model?